# How to Center 3 Bootstrap Block Modules in computer screen view?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-modal

[image: Screenshot]

Hello. How do I **center** these 3 block modules in Bootstrap? See how there's so much space on the right? The code fix is for Desktop and laptop view only because it will stack in mobile view.

I've tried different classes I found in online articles like . Nothing works.

```css
body {
    background: none;
}

#features {
    margin-top:20px;
}
.feature, .feature i, .feature h3, .feature .title_border {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;    
}
.feature {
    background:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    border: solid 1px #cccccc;
}
.feature p {
    margin-top:20px;   
    margin-bottom:30px;   
    font-size: 16px;
}

.feature i{
    font-size:80px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background:#0088CE;
    padding:30px;
    border-radius:50%;
    border: solid 3px #0088CE;
}
.feature h3 {
    color:#62BB47;  
}
.feature:hover {
    background:#F5F5F5;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,3em);
    -moz-transform: translate(0,3em);
    -o-transform: translate(0,3em);
    -ms-transform: translate(0,3em);
    transform: translate(0,3em);    
}
.feature:hover i{
    color: #62BB47;
    border-color:#0088CE;
    background:#FFFFFF;
}
.feature:hover .title_border {
    background-color:#1E825F;
    width:50%;
}
.feature .title_border {
    width: 0%;
    height: 3px;
    color: #0088CE;
    background:#0088CE;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
   <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
   
   
   <div class="container" id="features">
         
      <div class="col-md-3 feature">
             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i>
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                <div class="title_border"></div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quam urna, finibus quis mauris a, finibus interdum diam. Maecenas ultrices lacus at lobortis auctor.</p>
      </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 feature">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                <div class="title_border"></div>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quam urna, finibus quis mauris a, finibus interdum diam. Maecenas ultrices lacus at lobortis auctor.</p>
      </div>
    
            <div class="col-md-3 feature">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i>
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                <div class="title_border"></div>
                <p>Download the group enrollment forms. Select each form based on the State on the map chart.</p>
         </div>     
</div>
```

Comment: Be careful changing the padding on Bootstrap `col-*` to 20px, it will mess up the grid. It would be better to place `.feature` inside col.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's grid works on a 12 column system.  If you want to center it, but retain the `col-md-3` size, you'll need to do an offset (but that still doesn't work out evenly), i.e give the first feature a `col-md-offset-1`.  Otherwise, switch them all to `col-md-4` and it will space them out appropriately.

Comment: Thank you Dave. It's actually more complicated. Different logins display different amount of blocks. On one login there are 4 blocks. Another login there are only 3 blocks. Each block is col-md-3 because of the 4 blocks for the 12 column system.

Answer (score 0):

As it is 12 column system give col-md-4 then it perfectly works.Check this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <div class="container" id="features">
          <div class="row">   
      <div class="col-md-4 feature">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i>
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
            <div class="title_border"></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quam urna, finibus quis mauris a, finibus interdum diam. Maecenas ultrices lacus at lobortis auctor.</p>
      </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 feature">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
            <div class="title_border"></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quam urna, finibus quis mauris a, finibus interdum diam. Maecenas ultrices lacus at lobortis auctor.</p>
      </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 feature">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i>
          <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
          <div class="title_border"></div>
          <p>Download the group enrollment forms. Select each form based on the State on the map chart.</p>
         </div>     
          </div>
      </div>
```

As it is 12 column system give col-md-4 then it perfectly works.Check this

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <div class="container" id="features">
          <div class="row">   
      <div class="col-md-4 feature">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i>
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
            <div class="title_border"></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quam urna, finibus quis mauris a, finibus interdum diam. Maecenas ultrices lacus at lobortis auctor.</p>
      </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 feature">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
            <div class="title_border"></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quam urna, finibus quis mauris a, finibus interdum diam. Maecenas ultrices lacus at lobortis auctor.</p>
      </div>
          <div class="col-md-4 feature">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></i>
          <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
          <div class="title_border"></div>
          <p>Download the group enrollment forms. Select each form based on the State on the map chart.</p>
         </div>     
          </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually align them to center by adding the following css.

```
#features {
    text-align:center;
}

.col-md-3.feature{
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    }
```